# How to get value of index column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like following.

```
                  colName      
date        
2020-06-02 03:00:00 39
```

I can get value of each entry of colName using following. How to get date value?

```
for index, row in max_items.iterrows():
        print(str(row['colName]))
        // How to get date??
```

Comment: `print(index)` ?  pd.DataFrame.index returns a tuple of the index and row. The 'date' is in the index of the dataframe as you have displayed it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

### Anti-pattern Warning

First I want to highlight, this is an anti-pattern, using iteration is highly counterproductive.
There are extremely rare cases when you need to iterate through the pandas dataframes. Essentially, Map, Apply and applymap can achieve results efficiently.

---

Coming to the issue at hand:
you need to convert your index to datetime if not already there.

**Simple example:**

```
# Creating the dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/03/2018'), 
                   'test_value_a':[5, 6, 9], 
                   'test_value_b':[2, 5, 1]})

# Coverting date column into index of type datetime.
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)

# Dropping date column we had created
df1.drop(labels='date', axis="columns")
```

To print date, month, month name, day or day_name:

```
df1.index.date
df1.index.month
df1.index.month
df1.index.month_name
df1.index.day
df1.index.day_name
```

I would suggest read about **loc, iloc and ix** in the pandas' documentation that should help.
I hope I didn't veer off from the crux of the question.